# Getting Descendants from a Kendo dropdownlist value select

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am developing a web application using Kendo UI framework. HTML file is as follows:-

```
<div class="grand_parent">

    <div class="parent1"> 
        <div class="child1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div class="parent2">
        <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="spacer"></div>

    <div class="parent3">
        <div class="child3">
             <span>This content will be replaced</span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

'grand_parent' class will be repeated based on condition. In this 'child2' classes will be binded with Kendo dropdownlist.

```
$(".child2").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: options,
    change: onSelect,
    index: 0,
});


options = [
    {text:"Child1", value:1},
    {text:"Child2", value:2},
    {text:"Child3", value:3},
];

function onSelect(e){
    var value = e.sender.value();
    switch (value) {
        case 1:
            $(this).parentsUntil(".parent2").closest(".parent3").find(".child3").html("<span>Value1</span>");
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).parentsUntil(".parent2").closest(".parent3").find(".child3").html("<span>Value2</span>");
            break;
        case 3:
            $(this).parentsUntil(".parent2").closest(".parent3").find(".child3").html("<span>Value3</span>");
            break;
        default:
            $(this).parentsUntil(".parent2").closest(".parent3").find(".child3").html("<span>value restored</span>");
            break;
    }
}
```

My requirement is when I select a value from a child2 dropdownlist corresponding 'child3' content should be replaced.(Like when I select a value from child2 dropdownlist in the first row child3 in first row should be replaced). How can I do that?

Comment: 1) What should happens if you select child1 or child2 rather than child3? 
2) Are there other dropdownlist to manipulate in this process? (From your question above 'child1' and 'child3' elements are simple divs.)
3) In the switch case you wrote multiple times 'case1'.

Comment: @GiovanniRomio : It happened by mistake. As you mentioned child1 & child3 are simple divs. Oncly child2 classes will be binded with Kendodropdownlists.

Comment: What should happens if you select child1 or child2 rather than child3?

Comment: @GiovanniRomio : Child3 > span elemet's text will be replaced. The below answer by  is correct. I think the real problem was with 'this' reference. Anyway thanks you :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite few things you have to fix in your code.
First you should be selecting "this.element" or "this.wrapper".
Check this link:
[Kendo UI Widgets Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/wrapper-element#widget-dom-elements)

After that fix your switch cases.
And lastly fix your jQuery selectors:

```
$(this.element).closest(".parent2").siblings(".parent3").find(".child3").html("<span>Value1</span>");
```

Here is a link to see it in action:

http://dojo.telerik.com/eyupA